# How can I throw Exception for async function using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am writing test cases using xUnit and Moq.

I am using below code in Test class for testing `catch()` of another class method

```
private readonly  IADLS_Operations _iADLS_Operations;

[Fact]
public void CreateCSVFile_Failure()
{
    var dtData = new DataTable();
    string fileName = "";
   var   mockClient = new Mock<IHttpHandler>();

    this._iADLS_Operations = new ADLS_Operations(mockClient.Object);

    mockClient.Setup(repo => repo.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<HttpContent>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)));

    mockClient.Setup(repo => repo.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)));  // here I want to return Exception instead of BadRequest. How to do that.

    Exception ex = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => this._iADLS_Operations.CreateCSVFile(dtData, fileName).Result);
    Assert.Contains("Exception occurred while executing method:", ex.Message);
}
```

In below code, I want to return Exception instead of `BadRequest`.

```
mockClient.Setup(repo => repo.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)));
```

How to achieve that.

Comment: `Throws` instead of `Returns`...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Considering the asynchronous nature of the code under test, it would be better if the test code be asynchronous as well. Moq is async capable

```
[Fact]
public async Task CreateCSVFile_Failure() {
    //Arrange
    var dtData = new DataTable();
    string fileName = "";
    var mockClient = new Mock<IHttpHandler>();

    this._iADLS_Operations = new ADLS_Operations(mockClient.Object);

    mockClient
        .Setup(repo => repo.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<HttpContent>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));

    mockClient
        .Setup(repo => repo.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ThrowsAsync(new Exception("Some message here"));

    //Act 
    Func<Task> act = () => this._iADLS_Operations.CreateCSVFile(dtData, fileName);

    //Assert
    Exception ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(act);
    Assert.Contains("Exception occurred while executing method:", ex.Message);
}
```

Note the use of Moq's `ReturnsAsync` and `ThrowsAsync` in the setup, along with xUnit's `Assert.ThrowsAsync`

This now allows you to avoid making blocking calls like `.Result` which could potentially lead to deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. StackOverflow never disappoints me when I am in trouble.Superb explanation.Issue resolved.

Answer (score 5):

As @Johnny mentioned in the comments, you can replace the `Returns` in your code with `Throws` like:

```
mockClient.Setup(repo => repo.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Throws(new Exception("exception message"));
```

In addition, you could also throw an exception like:

```
mockClient.Setup(repo => repo.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
```

You can find more information about throwing exceptions and moq [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).